# Passing argument to function assigned to a variable

Tags: python

I realize this is a basic question, but I can't figure out how to answer it. Consider the following code example:

```
def a_function(someval=None):
    if a_function:
        print(a_function)
    else:
        print("None")

foo = a_function

print(foo(1))
```

> None

I understand I can assign a function (or anything, really) to a variable because functions are first class objections, and that I can call the function via foo().

Question: How do I pass an argument to the function if it is assigned to a variable?

In the example above, it's apparent that the (1) is not being passed to a_function().

Thank you for your help with this.

Comment: _"it's apparent that the (1) is not being passed to a_function()."_ That's not apparent to me. You never do anything with the `someval` value, so you can't make any assertions about its contents.

Comment: Your function has no `return` statement. It'll *always* return None, and then `print` prints that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your function definition as given in the question is going to always return `None`.

```
def a_function(someval=None):
    if someval:
        print(someval)
    else:
        print("None")
```

And now `foo(1)` should print `1`.

Comment: that's going to print `1`  and `None` because you print the return value of the function which is None

Comment: This *prints* `1` and *returns* `None`.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are asking about [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial):

```
from functools import partial

def a_function(someval=None):
    if someval:
        print(someval)
    else:
        print("None")

foo = partial(a_function, 1)
foo()  # prints 1
```

`foo` here is a partial function which "freezes" the `a_function` function with a specific argument.

Answer (score 2):

Your code simply needs some rework:

```
def a_function(someval=None):
    print(someval)

foo = a_function

foo(1)
```

And then the result:

```
1
```

Before that you were checking `if a_function` which is always `True` because the function is an object and that evaluates to `True`

And you were additionally printing the return value of `a_function` which is `None` because the function has no return statement.